# Google map info window, add data-attribute id then catch the element via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, kml

Is it possible to add a data-attribute id in the info window of google map in kml then select the info window via javascript or jquery?

I'm aware you can add html easily in the info window if the map is generated via javascript but when pulling the contents via kml it removes any html. Below is how I generate the map

```js
var olat = parseFloat(d.development_lat);
var olng = parseFloat(d.development_long);
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: olat, lng: olng}
  });
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://dummy-url-of-the-kml.kml',
    map: map
  });
}
initMap();
```

The content of the kml are multiple polygons of land parcels.
The reason is, i want it so that each info window will have a unique data attribute then catch it via javascript or jquery to make a customed url link when you click the info window.

Any alternatives are open as long as the data is coming from a kml file

Comment: Are you able to create a complete (working) example? jsfiddle/codepen/snippet? it will help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your issue.

Comment: yes it is possible .But after display the whole code may sugest